# How to filter gte,lte date on datetime field?

Tags: django, postgresql, datetime, django-filter, django-postgresql

I'm trying to figure out how to filter QuerySet using date extracted from datetime.

I use `Django-filter` and I can't compose such lookup without iterating over QuerySet which is very uneffective.

I tried `datetime__date__gte` which doesn't work.

```
class MyReservationsFilter(FilterSet):
    datetime__lte = DateFilter(method='datetime_filter',name='lte')
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = {'status': ['exact'],
                  # 'datetime': ['lte', 'gte'],
                  'destination_from': ['exact'],
                  'destination_to': ['exact'],}


    def datetime_filter(self, queryset, name, value):

        lookup = 'datetime__'+name
        return queryset.filter(**{lookup:value})
```

Do you know what to do?

I can't use `datetime__lte/gte` because:

I have a `Reservation` object r.

```
>> r.datetime
>> datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 31, 17, 55)
>> r.datetime.date()
>> datetime.date(2017, 8, 31)
```

So now I try to filter based on date:

```
Reservation.objects.filter(datetime__lte=datetime.date(2017, 8, 31),datetime__gte=datetime.date(2017, 8, 31))

>> []
```

It's because it doesn't look only on date but on time too. So I need to extract date to be able to filter properly.

Answer (score 23):

When you want to only compare the date portion of a datetime field, you need to use the `date` transform. eg,

```py
Reservation.objects.filter(datetime__date__lte=date(2017, 1, 1))
```

Getting this to work with `FilterSet`s doesn't require a custom method. Filter expressions are constructed by joining the `field_name` and `lookup_expr` arguments of the filter constructor. The `field_name` argument should correspond to the model field name, and the `lookup_expr` should account for the transform and lookup type.

```py
class MyReservationsFilter(FilterSet):
    datetime__lte = DateFilter(field_name='datetime', lookup_expr='date__lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Django 1.9 you can filter with

```
Model.objects.filter(datetime__date = date.today())
```

if not you can filter like this

```
Model.objects.filter(post_date__year=date.year,
                     post_date__month=date.month,
                     post_date__day=date.day)
```

this is way too much typing I know. But this is the only way I guess.

Found this here: https://chrisbartos.com/articles/how-to-filter-a-datetimefield-by-todays-date-in-django/